# Removing blue block of active hyperlink?

Tags: html, css, mobile, hyperlink

On a mobile device, when a hyperlink is clicked, a blue box appears for a brief second. It doesn't matter if the hyperlink is text or an image, it still appears. Is there a way to turn this off?

I don't want to turn it off on all items. I just have some hyperlinks embedded in none rectangular images and i think it looks ugly.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `a:active { outline: none; }` ?

Comment: The blue box still appears. 

.scrollToTheTop:active {
 outline: none;
}

I've also tried border:0; And background-color: transparent;

Comment: Does this behavior occur with any desktop browsers? Your best bet might be to try to get something with an element inspector of some kind to see if it's even a css style that's being applied. Whether or not it'll be adjustable is another matter, could be some built-in accessibility setting on the mobile device too?

Comment: It doesn't show the blue box on desktop browsers, just mobile devices. I did wonder if it could be a hard wired accessibility setting of the mobile browser but wondered if there was a way around it in html/css/js.